# HTTPS under Amazon EBS + Apache on ubuntu on EC2 not redirecting HTTP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have a EBS machine running ubuntu 16.04 and Apache2 which is receiving HTTPS requests from a EBS. I`m having problems on trying to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.

So far I tried to redirect using `.htacces` and `mod_rewrite`.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

How can I redirect the HTTP requests to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I'm getting "too many redirections" hen I try to access the url.

Comment: So your page is probably directing you back to HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Instead of using a .htaccess file I wrote the rules on apache .conf file.

Here is it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```